# cannot connect to ftp server from lan?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, ubuntu-11.04

i am trying to make my ftp server accessible (for download only) by other computers on my LAN using anonymous user and without password, when i connect to it from the same pc using filezilla it works well but when trying from other PCs on the LAN it says

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error: Could not connect to server
```

iam using Ubuntu 11.04 and this is my configuration:

vsftpd.conf :

```
anon_root=/home/ftp
no_anon_password=YES
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=NO
write_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/vsftpd.pem
```

the directory /home/ftp permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 2012-02-04 19:39 ftp
```

i think since it says "connection established" there is no problem with the iptables right?
and the selinux is not installed either! i have lost many hours on this problem :'( !! any help please..

Answer (score 0):

Just because it says connection established does not mean there is no iptables issue. Try stopping your firewall first, since you are not saying if you are using active or passive ftp.
The other thing you can try is stopping apparmor (if installed).

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
```

Comment: my firewall is off i forgot to mention that.. i used "ufw disable "

Comment: and since i didn't put pasv_enable=NO it is by default YES as i read in the man page, but yes i think it is ports issue because as i read the ftp uses 2 ports one for control and the other for data transfer and i think the problem is with the data transfer ports!